# CSS Flexbox - How to make flex item shrink to fit flex container?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to make my flex item shrinked to fit flex container, but it does not seem to work.

Here is my code:

I am using React and AntD (refer to below for the elements in the console)

```
<Card className='items-col' title='Item List'>
    <MUIDataTable
        data={items}
        columns={columns}
        options={options}
    />
</Card>
```

CSS:

```
.quotation-grid .items-col {
    grid-area: items;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    height: 100%;
}

.quotation-grid .items-col .ant-card-body {
    flex: 0 1 0;
}
```

Elements:

```
<div class='ant-card items-col ant-card-bordered'>
    <div class='ant-card-head'>...</div>
    <div class='ant-card-body'>...</div> // i want this to shrink to fit the container
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Essentially, I am doing this so that I can set the inner rows of the table to be `overflow: auto` so that the scrolling of the overflow is only within the rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by

```
flex: 0 1 0;
```

Aren't you telling the flexbox "My item should have a height of 0, if we overflow, shrink it"? It can never shrink, as it for the flexbox it already only demands 0 height.

Maybe you rather want to do "flex: 1 0 0" which is the same as "flex: 1". Which means "My item should have a height of 0, but if we still have space, grow" --- or "take the available space". However, if the content still is too big, it will still overflow. You may need a container around that with

```
flex: 1;
overflow: auto;
```

that then will take all availalable space and will never be forced to grow by it's children.